# Is there a way to make the time outputted by datetime.datetime.now() a valid parameter for Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file, file-rename

I'm currently working on an automatic file sorter with Python and want to rename pictures and videos by date and time they have been moved to the correct folder.
My problem is, when I try to rename my file using os.rename, I get this Error:

OSError: [WinError 87] Falscher Parameter: 'C:/Users/TimWo/OneDrive/Desktop/Pictures/Test.jpg' -> 'C:/Users/TimWo/OneDrive/Desktop/Pictures/Aug 23, 15:47:20.jpg'

(Falscher Parameter means incorrect parameter in German)

I found out that this seems to be a Windows problem but couldn't find a fix/workaround.

This is my Code for moving and renaming the files (only the relevant parts):

```
for file in dir:

    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
        
    elif file.lower().endswith(".mov"):
        shutil.move(pathToWatch + "/" + file, vidPath)
        os.rename(os.path.join(vidPat + "/", file), os.path.join(vidPath + "/", dt.strftime("%b %d, %X") + ".mov"))
        
    elif file.lower().endswith(".mp4"):
        shutil.move(pathToWatch + "/" + file, vidPath)
        os.rename(os.path.join(vidPath + "/", file), os.path.join(vidPath + "/", dt.strftime("%b %d, %X") + ".mp4"))
        
    elif file.lower().endswith(".png"):
        shutil.move(pathToWatch + "/" + file, picPath)
        os.rename(os.path.join(picPat + "/", file), os.path.join(picPath + "/", dt.strftime("%b %d, %X") + ".png"))

    elif file.lower().endswith(".jpg"):
        shutil.move(pathToWatch + "/" + file, picPath)
        os.rename(os.path.join(picPath + "/", file), os.path.join(picPath + "/", dt.strftime("%b %d, %X") + ".jpg"))
```

All Paths are correctly defined and it all works when I use a preset String to rename the files.

Does anyone know how i could get this to work?

Comment: You will have to use something other than colon. Try for example `.replace(':', '_')` at the end - or use `%H_%M_%S` explicitly instead of `%X`. (Doesn't have to be `_` of course - you might prefer `.` or whatever.)

Comment: Alternatively, use a decent operating system ;-)

Comment: Thanks, replacing %X with %H_%M_%S works, I didn't think it would be that simple. :D

Comment: Yeah i kinda want to use linux but for some reason I'm just stuck with Windows.